# In Javafx CSS, does a selector always choose a class?

Tags: css, javafx

For example, `.button{}` selects `Button` class and `.text-area{}` selects `TextArea` class. So when it does that, does that select the entire class itself(opposed to specific instances of a class)? If it does, is there any way for Javafx CSS to select a specific instance of a class or just in general, a variable?

Comment: Why not set an id and select by id? See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/apply-css.htm#sthref390

Comment: James_D: So are you saying that with this 'selector{}' way of doing it, there's no way to select an instance of a class or a variable?

Comment: No, I'm saying that if you use an id selector instead of the class selector you showed in your question, you can select a single node, instead of all nodes with a given class. Read the docs I linked.

Answer (score 1):

You're selecting every `Node` containing the style class contained in the location where you apply the css stylesheet.

For some nodes one or more style classes are added, it's also possible to modify them.

```
someNode.getStyleClass().setAll("my-class");
```

To select individual nodes though usually a id selector is used:

```
mySpecialButton.setId("special-button");
```

**CSS**

```css
#special-button {
    /* TODO... */
}
```